# Swift 4 JSON Decoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, decodable

I know this has been covered in other questions, but I've followed them and I'm still stumped. Here is my JSON structure:

```
      {
       "FindBoatResult": {
       "num_boats": 10,
       "boat": [
         {
           "num_segments": 1,
           "segments": [
              {
               "ident": "String",
                "origin" : {
                         "code" : "String"
                 },
           },
         ]
        }
```

etc...but thats as deep as the structure goes. there are multiple returns of "segments" in each JSON response. In Swift I have this code.

```
struct Result : Decodable {
    let FindBoatResult : FindBoatResult
}
struct FindBoatResult : Decodable {
    let boats : Boats
    let num_boats : Int
}
struct Boats : Decodable {
    let segments : [Segments]
}
struct Segments : Decodable {
    let ident : String?
    let origin : Origin
}
struct Origin : Decodable {
    let code : String
}

func getBoats() {

let urlString = "http://myApi"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        //print(dataAsString)

        do {
            let boats = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(FindBoatResult.self, from: data)

            print(boats)
        } catch {
            print(err) 
        }  
    }.resume()
}
```

This fails and throws err but err prints as nil..so I can't tell what I'm missing. dataAsString prints out the JSON as expected, so I know "data" is good.

Comment: You have to print error as `print(error)`

Comment: ... or to avoid any confusion between the error passed by `dataTask` I'd give it a unique name, e.g. `do { ... } catch let parseError { print(parseError) }`.

Answer (score 1):

I detected a couple of minor issues. Try replacing this:

```
struct FindBoatResult: Decodable {
    let boats: Boats
    let num_boats: Int
}
struct Boats: Decodable {
    let segments: [Segments]
}
```

with:

```
struct FindBoatResult: Decodable {
    let boat: [Boat]
    let num_boats: Int
}
struct Boat: Decodable {
    let segments: [Segments]
}
```

Finally, decode using the `Result` type (not `FindBoatResult`):

```
JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Paulo's answer, I might further suggest that if you're stuck with JSON that has keys that don't conform to Swift conventions for property names, that you use the `CodingKeys` pattern to translate JSON keys to better Swift property names, e.g.:

```
struct BoatResult: Decodable {           // I'd simplify this name
    let boatCollection: BoatCollection

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case boatCollection = "FindBoatResult"
    }
}

struct BoatCollection: Decodable {       // I'd simplify this, too, removing "Find" from the name; verbs are for methods, not properties 
    let boats: [Boat]
    let numberOfBoats: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case boats = "boat"              // "boat" isn't great property name for an array of boats, so let's map the poor JSON key to better Swift name here
        case numberOfBoats = "num_boats" // likewise, let's map the "_" name with better camelCase property name
    }
}

struct Boat: Decodable {                 // This entity represents a single boat, so let's use "Boat", not "Boats"
    let segments: [Segment]
}

struct Segment: Decodable {              // This entity represents a single segment, so let's use "Segment", not "Segments"
    let identifier: String
    let origin: Origin

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case identifier = "ident"        // `ident` isn't a common name for identifier, so let's use something more logical
        case origin
    }
}

struct Origin: Decodable {
    let code: String
}
```

So, for example, use a plurals (e.g. `boats`) when you're representing an array of objects, and use `CodingKeys` to map the misleading `boat` JSON key to this better named `boats` array reference. Or when you have a key like `num_boats`, don't feel like you have to use that bad name in your Swift property and use something better like `numberOfBoats` (or `count` or whatever), and lose the `_` syntax which is very unSwifty.

Clearly, if you're in control of the design of the JSON, you can just fix some of these poorly chosen key names there, but even where you decide you want your web service to use the `_` syntax, go ahead and use `CodingKeys` to make sure your Swift objects honor the camelCase convention.

Comment: I'm unclear why you cannot post a question. If it's a S.O. issue, then find a different venue for posting a question. If it's a work/confidentiality issue, then anonymize the question sufficiently to address those concerns. But trying to diagnose your issue here in comments is not the right place. You should remove the above comments.